# Position children components in React via prop in parent component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

### Context

I have this parent `HeaderComponent` which receives `HeaderItemComponent` as children:

```
export const HeaderComponent: React.FC<HeaderComponentProps> = ({
    children,
    className,
}: HeaderComponentProps): ReactElement => <div className={classnames(styles.header, className)}>{children}</div>;

export const HeaderItemComponent: React.FC<HeaderComponentProps> = ({
    children,
    left,
    center,
    right,
}: HeaderComponentProps): ReactElement => {
    const headerItemClassnames = classnames(
        left ? styles.left : '',
        center ? styles.center : '',
        right ? styles.right : ''
    );

    return <div className={headerItemClassnames}>{children}</div>;
```

Now, I want to call the `HeaderComponent` in other components with a flexible amount of `HeaderItemComponent` as children of `HeaderComponent`.

The fixed positioning of the `HeaderComponent` should look like this:

**`HeaderItemComponent` left | `HeaderItemComponent` center | `HeaderItemComponent` right**

No matter if I render one `HeaderItemComponent` or two or three. The position should always be like above.

The component that renders the `HeaderComponent` should decide on the position of `HeaderItemComponent` via a prop like `left`, `center` and / or `right`:

```
<HeaderComponent>
    <HeaderItemComponent center> ... </HeaderItemComponent>
    <HeaderItemComponent right> ... </HeaderItemComponent>
</HeaderComponent>
```

In the above case there is only `center` and `right` - hence the positioning should look like this:

**EMPTY SPACE | `HeaderItemComponent` center | `HeaderItemComponent` right**

### Problem

Right now, the stylesheet of `HeaderComponent` looks like this:

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
```

I could not find a way to provide `.left`, `.center` and `.right` classes to provide the `HeaderItemComponent` with a fixed position via the prop independent of whether one, two or all children are rendered.